# How to classify select results in Ms Access query sql view

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm creating a database in Ms Access for Cars. This Car table has the following attributes:
name type country. I need help with a query that selects all cars classified by type.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have a `WHERE` clause, example

```
SELECT *
FROM   Cars
WHERE  CarType = 'desired_type'
```

a `WHERE`, basically, filters the result based on a specified criteria.